# Airport Extreme broadcast from laptop?

Tags: networking, mac, wireless-networking, macbook-pro, airport-extreme

I have an Airport Extreme and a Macbook Pro. I want to connect the Airport to the Macbook and provide wifi service to an area. I want devices that connect to the Airport to be able to connect to the web as well as servers that I host locally on the laptop.

So for example, an iPad could connect to [google.com](http://google.com) and also to [some.ip.on.laptop].

How do I set up the Airport Extreme and Macbook to support this?

Edit 1:
I was able to temporarily (hopefully it's temporary) use the macbook itself as a hotspot. This allows the IPads connecting to it to also connect to the web, which is exactly what I needed (the ability to connect to both the machine's local network as well as the wide area network).
I'd still like to get this working through my airport extreme, as I believe it will offer a more powerful signal and wider range.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up abandoning a setup that allowed devices to connect to both the laptop and the internet through the airport extreme. After getting assistance from the IT manager at my workplace, we were able to resolve the issue as a completely local network.

Our solution was to:

- connect the laptop into one of the airport's "endnode jacks" (one of the 3 jacks and not the ethernet jack).
- disconnect any WAN ethernet.